Finding an irrational value for log
Given positive reals $a$, $b$, how can I prove that one of $\log_a(a^n+b^m)$ must be irrational, where $m$ and $n$ can take any positive integer value? This seems trivial and is just a lemma that I need to use to solve another question, but I can't seem to find a quick solution. I tried some $a^p + a^q=a^r$ for rational $p,q,r$, but still couldn't find anything useful.

If $a$ and $b$ are assumed to be integers: Indeed this is true even if $m$ is fixed. Let's show even that $\log_a(a^n+b)$ must be irrational for all sufficiently large $n$, assuming $a>1$.
Write $a=\alpha^k$ where $\alpha$ is not a perfect power. Then $\log_a(a^n+b) = \frac1k \log_\alpha(\alpha^{kn}+b)$ is rational precisely when $\log_\alpha(\alpha^{kn}+b)$ is rational. But $\log_\alpha(\alpha^{kn}+b)$ being rational implies that $\log_\alpha(\alpha^{kn}+b)$ is actually an integer (since $\alpha$ is not a perfect power), and therefore $\alpha^{kn}+b$ is an integer power of $\alpha$. On the other hand, when $n$ is large enough, $b$ will be less than $\alpha^{kn+1}-\alpha^{kn}$, which means that $\alpha^{kn}+b$ is strictly between two powers of $\alpha$ and thus cannot itself be a power of $\alpha$.

Could you explain what you mean by perfect power and how you get from rational to integer?

@JermaineCole It means that $\alpha$ is not of the form $\beta^k$ with integers and $k>1$. If $\alpha^{kn}+b=\alpha^r$ where $r$ is rational, then $\alpha^r$ is an integer, and then $r$ must be an integer because $\alpha$ is not a perfect power.

@Milten here are you assuming that $a$ and $b$ are integers?

@JermaineCole Oh, yes I was! Rereading your question, I guess they should be any positive real numbers actually? I suspect Greg Martin was assuming that too, but I can't speak for them of course

Oh—yes I was certainly assuming that $a$ and $b$ are integers, though I now see that wasn't stated anywhere. Perhaps the OP can clarify?

@GregMartin Yes, how would this question be solved if $a$ and $b$ were just positive reals?
